# JSONP callback in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart

I have been trying to get basic JSONP working in Dart and I am getting stuck. Reading [this blog post](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/03/jsonp-with-dart.html) as well as this [this blog](http://thedartlanguage.blogspot.com/2012/10/a-yahoo-music-webservice-with-dart.html) show that I should use `window.on.message.add(dataReceived);` to get a MessageEvent and retrieve data from the event.

Dart complains that "There is no such getter 'message' in events". In addition, I looked up different ways of getting a MessageEvent but it seems to be something completely unrelated  (WebSockets?) and is not what I actually need.

If anybody can explain what is going on and how to really use JSONP in Dart, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax has changed

```dart
window.onMessage.listen(dataReceived);
```

Comment: I went through all the methods and still somehow missed that one... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use what is described in the articles you point anymore. You can use [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-js) :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js';

void main() {
  // Create a jsFunction to handle the response.
  context['processData'] = (JsObject jsonDatas) {
    // call with JSON datas
  };

  // make the call
  ScriptElement script = new Element.tag("script");
  script.src = "https://${url}?callback=processData";
  document.body.children.add(script);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a [blog post](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/2015/10/22/JSONP-in-Dart/) on this myself as I was running into similar problems.

I first cover a few prerequisite things like [Verifying CORS Compliance](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/2015/10/22/JSONP-in-Dart/#Verifying_CORS_Compliance) and [Verifying JSONP Support](https://theknowledgeaccelerator.com/2015/10/22/JSONP-in-Dart/#Verifying_JSONP_Compliance)

I too ended up registering with the updated method:

`window.onMessage.listen(dataReceived);`

I then had a fairly simple method to dynamically create the script tag in Dart as well (my requirement was that I had to use Dart exclusively and couldn't touch the website source files):

```
void _createScriptTag()
{
    String requestString = """function callbackForJsonpApi(s) {
        s.target="dartJsonHandler";
        window.postMessage(JSON.stringify(s), '*');
        }""";
    ScriptElement script = new ScriptElement();
    script.innerHtml = requestString;
    document.body.children.add(script);
}
```

I then invoked it from Dart with some simple logic that I wrapped in a method for convenience.

```
void getStockQuote(String tickerId)
{   
    String requestString = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/" + tickerId + "/quote?format=json&callback=callbackForJsonpApi";

    ScriptElement script = new ScriptElement();
    script.src = requestString;
    document.body.children.add(script);
}
```

If you are using [dart:js](https://api.dartlang.org/1.12.2/dart-js/dart-js-library.html) I find Alexandre's Answer useful and, after upvoting Alexandre, I have updated my post to include the simplified version as well:

```
context['callbackForJsonpApi'] = (JsObject jsonData) 
{
  //Process JSON data here...
};
```

This obviously eliminates the need for the `onMessage` and `_createScriptTag` above, and can be invoked the same as before.

I decided to keep both approaches, however, as I have noticed over time the Dart APIs changing and it seems to be a good idea to have a fallback if needed.